# [Python]Вывод сгруппированных элементов кортежа(первый словарь, второй список

Tags: python, списки, словари, group-by, tuple

Прошу помощи, не получается пройти циклом только по первому элементу(словарям) каждого кортежа.
Максимум что получилось:

```
data = [
    ({'a':a, 'b':b},[a,b]),
    ({'a':a, 'b':b},[a,b]),
    ({'a':a, 'b':b},[a,b])
   ]

a = lambda a: a.a
for tuples in data:
    for dict_and_list in tuples:
        print('\n', dict_and_list)
```

получаю вывод: {'a':a, 'b':b}
              [a,b]
              итд 
А необходимо проходить по словарю и группировать его по определенному значению. 
Проблема в том, что не могу придумать как сделать так, чтобы следующий цикл пробегал только по первому элементу кортежей(словарям) чтобы дальше сгруппировать.

Добрался до такого варианта, но теперь не получается группировать и вывести вместе элементы словаря и элементы списка.

```
 a = lambda a: a.a
    tags = [tuples[0] for tuples in data]
    name_and_path = [tuples[1] for tuples in data]
    group_by = groupby(tags, a)
    for key, info in group_by:
        print("\n", key)
        for tag in info:
            print('{0}'.format(tag.a))
```

Answer (score 0):

Словари в Python - `неупорядоченные` коллекции произвольных объектов с доступом по ключу.

```
data = [
    ({'a': 'a1', 'b': 'b1'}, ['a11','b11']),
    ({'a': 'a2', 'b': 'b2'}, ['a12','b12']),
    ({'a': 'a3', 'b': 'b3'}, ['a13','b13']),
    ({'b': 'b4', 'a': 'a4'}, ['a14','b14'])
]

result = [(tuples[0]['a'],tuples[0]['b'],tuples[1]) for tuples in data]

from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(result)

[('a1', 'b1', ['a11', 'b11']),
 ('a2', 'b2', ['a12', 'b12']),
 ('a3', 'b3', ['a13', 'b13']),
 ('a4', 'b4', ['a14', 'b14'])]
```

Comment: Вы не так поняли(видимо я плохо описал вопрос), словарь тут первый элемент каждого кортежа, второй список. Необходимо пройти по первому элементу кортежа и сгруппировать по определенному значению ключа(вторая часть кода в вопросе), но при этом также вывести в каждой группе другие значения словаря и списка(второго элемента кортежа). Без списка(второго элемента кортежа) все получается, а вот как воткнуть ещё список в группировку и вывод не могу придумать

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста пример входных данных и кукой результат вы хотите получить.

Comment: Пример входных данных это массив data - список кортежей, в каждом кортеже первый элемент словарь, а второй список. Необходимо сгруппировать вывод через groupby по одному из значей словаря и далее в каждой группе вывести все оставшиеся значения словаря и списка которые относятся к этой группе. Если отбросить список, то все получается(пример кода в конце вопроса), но необходимо сделать это вместе со списком. Пример вывода: а1 - первая группа, под ней остальные значения словарей в которых есть значение а1, а также все элементы списков из кортежей в который есть словарь со значением а1

Comment: попробуйте так: `[(tuples[0]['a'],tuples[0]['b'],tuples[1]) for tuples in data]`

Comment: Спасибо, утром тогда попробую и отпишу что получилось

Comment: Такой вариант не подходит(((